# How to keep value of selected value after form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms, yii2-advanced-app

I know there are a lot of questions related to it but believe me, no solution is working for me.

```
 <form action="index" method="post" >
            <select id="s" name="dtype" class="dropdown" required
                    style="float: left; text-align: left;width: 20%; margin: 10px;">
                <option value="400">Select Data Type</option>
                <option value="401">Current</option>
                <option value="402">Voltage</option>
                <option value="403">kWh</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following

```
<option <?php if ($_GET['dtype'] == '401') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="401">Current</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['dtype'] == '402') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="402">Voltage</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['dtype'] == '402') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="402">kwh</option>
```

Tried below solution

1. [Keep values selected after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246257/8919244)
2. [PHP keep dropdown value after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36072401/8919244)

All the solution gives me `unidentified index: dtype` error

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it is `selected="selected"`.

Answer (score 2):

In your form you have: `method="post"`
And then you use the `$_GET['dtype']`
Either change the method of the form to `method="get"` or change the if conditions to check for `$_POST['dtype']`.

That's why it says *unidentified index*. You are sending the data as **post** and trying to get it from the **$_GET** array.

Apart from this, if you are using xhtml the attribute value should be `selected="selected"` whereas if you use an html 5 doctype it should be just `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

The first option (Select Data Type) must have an empty value in order for "required" option to work.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <select id="s" name="dtype" class="dropdown" required style="...">
        <option value="">Select Data Type</option>
        <option value="401" <?php if(isset($_POST['dtype']) && $_POST['dtype']=="401") {echo'selected';} ?>>Current</option>
        <option value="402" <?php if(isset($_POST['dtype']) && $_POST['dtype']=="402") {echo'selected';} ?>>Voltage</option>
        <option value="403" <?php if(isset($_POST['dtype']) && $_POST['dtype']=="403") {echo'selected';} ?>>kWh</option>
    </select>
</form>
```